# Flatten Nested Array and Aggregate in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My table column has nested arrays in a Snowflake database. I want to perform some aggregations using SQL (Snowflake SQL).

My table name is: DATA

The PROJ column is of VARIANT data type. The nested arrays will not always be 3, and I demonstrated that in the DATA table.

```
| ID |             PROJ              | LOCATION |
|----|-------------------------------|----------|
| 1  |[[0, 4], [1, 30], [10, 20]]    |    S     |
| 2  |[[0, 2], [1, 20]]              |    S     |
| 3  |[[0, 8], [1, 10], [10, 100]]   |    S     |

Desired Output:

| Index | LOCATION |  Min | Max | Mean|
|-------|----------|------|-----|-----|
| 0     |    S     |  2   |  8  | 4.66|
| 1     |    S     |  10  |  30 | 20  |
| 10    |    S     |  20  |  100| 60  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the nested array should be flattened, then Index is the first element of subarray and Value is the second element(array is 0-based):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DATA
AS
SELECT 1 AS ID, [[0, 4], [1, 30], [10, 20]]   AS PROJ UNION
SELECT 2 AS ID, [[0, 2], [1, 20]]             AS PROJ UNION
SELECT 3 AS ID, [[0, 8], [1, 10], [10, 100]]  AS PROJ;
```

Query:

```
SELECT s.VALUE[0]::INT AS Index,
       MIN(s.VALUE[1]::INT) AS MinValue,
       MAX(s.VALUE[1]::INT) AS MaxValue,
       AVG(s.VALUE[1]::INT) AS MeanValue
FROM DATA
,LATERAL FLATTEN(input=> PROJ) s
GROUP BY s.VALUE[0]::INT
ORDER BY Index;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lukasz! @LukaszSzozda. What if I have another column I would like to keep in my output? Edited the question so you could see what I mean.

Comment: @Diego-S Please do not edit question that invalidates existing answers. It should be another question. Plus it is not defined how to choose the row in case if location is different between rows. - sample: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRHnh.png

Comment: Sorry bout that. The location is the same for all, would that  i.stack.imgur.com/GRHnh.png still work?

Comment: @Diego-S If they are the same than wrapping with agg function will work: `,MIN(location) AS location`